# When I disable the poll module my add content page doesn't work. Why?

Tags: 7, nodes

Im on d7. I no longer want to have a poll on my site. For some reason when I disable the poll module, the add content page becomes blank and says I have not yet created any content types. I have three other content types on my site and they display fine in the admin panel, just not on the node add page. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cache can often be a source to weird problems, clearing it could help. The poll module won't effect if other content types are active or not, so the problem shouldn't be related to the poll module directly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was due to the weird bug in the navigation menu that creates multiple empty add content links. Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "weird bug"? You could also post a screenshot. Thanks!